# Remap ~ key to space bar

Tags: linux, laptop, debian, keyboard, button-remapping

I have a relatively old laptop that works quite good, but the spacebar is broken. I would not like to use an external keyboard as it is bulky and the laptop keyboard is quite good. I would like to remap the "~" key to the spacebar.

OS: Bunsenlabs Linux (Based on debian)
Laptop: Core 2 duo 2007 black macbook with upgraded 4GB ram

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to leave this answer as a comment, but I believe this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382 Should apply to a Debian based O/S, or at least be enough to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: From Steve Davies' comment-as-an-answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382

Comment: @Steve Davies Could you guide me as to what to put in the configuration file?